# Почему $(this) не работает?

Tags: jquery

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dropb').hide();
    
     $('.menu-item').bind('click', function(){
       $(this).find('.dropb').css("display","block");
     });
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона</a>
      <ul class="dropb">
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы при нажатии был слайд тоггл, но думаю, что селектор не правильно поставлен.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, почему `$(this)` не работает?

P.S.: jquery подключил

Comment: на css("display","block"); не обращайте внимания я просто экспериментировал, там поидее slideToggle();

Comment: вообще то эту функцию следовало бы так написать $(this).find('.dropb').css({"display":"block"});

Comment: `bind`? Какая версия jQuery? Уже давно надо использовать `on`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.menu-item').click(function() {
    $('.dropb').fadeOut(0); // прячем открытые блоки
    $(this).children('.dropb').toggle(100);

  });

});
```

```css
.dropb {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона</a>
    <ul class="dropb">
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона</a>
    <ul class="dropb">
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы другие выплывающие менюшки закрывались

Comment: подправил пример кода. Я бы вам рекомендовал изначально для `dropb` прописать в стилях `display: none;` и тогда в скрипте можно будет в начале убрать строку `$('.dropb').fadeOut(0);`

Comment: `children`? o_O

Answer (score 5):

Вообще говоря, `$(this)` у вас работает. Не работает у вас `.find('.dropb')` - потому что элементы `.dropb` не являются дочерними для `.menu-item`.

Надо искать от родителя:

```
$(this).parent().find('.dropb')...
```

Comment: все ясно я подумал что .menu-item находится в div

Comment: а вот так? $(".menu-item").siblings()...

Comment: @perfect да, так тоже можно

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropb').hide();

  $('.menu-item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона </a>
  <ul class="dropb">
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите мой пример

```js
$(".menu-item").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().toggle(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона</a>
  <ul class="dropb">
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

только не стоит на ссылки вешать дополнительные подписки на click событие.

Comment: У вас обработчик события повешен не на тот элемент

Comment: @PavelMayorov , поправил

Comment: У вас теперь заголовок исчезает вместе с выпадающим меню :)

Comment: а как надо?, недолго и фильтр подставить )

Comment: Разумеется, заголовок не должен исчезать. А выпадающее меню - так вообще у автора изначально скрыто.

Comment: тогда просто в ф-ю siblings() надо передать то что ищем например так siblings(".dropb") и все.

Answer (score -1):

`$(this)` в данном случае - это элемент ссылки, внутри него нет `.dprop`.

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropb').hide();

    $('.menu-item').on('click', function(){
         $('.dropb').toggle();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Утепление и отделка балкона</a>
  <ul class="dropb">
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
    <li><a href="">fdsfdfsf</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: если в коде будет несколько ссылок с подменю с классом '.dropb', то ваш код будет не корректен...